# PostgreSQl correct lock on creation of new entity

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I have two concurrent transactions which check if appropriate PostgreSQL table record exists and if no - try to insert a new one.

I have the following Spring Data repository method:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
TaskApplication findByUserAndTask(User user, Task task);
```

As you may see I have added `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` there. Inside of my service method I check if entity exists and if no, create a new one:

```
@Transactional
public TaskApplication createIfNotExists(User user, Task task) {
    TaskApplication taskApplication = taskApplicationRepository.findByUserAndTask(user, task);
    if (taskApplication == null) {
        taskApplication = create(user, task);
    }
}
```

I also added unique constraint on `tasks_applications (user_id, task_id)` fields.

```
ALTER TABLE public.task_applications 
ADD CONSTRAINT "task_applications-user_id_task_id_unique" 
UNIQUE (user_id, task_id)
```

automatically created corresponding unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "task_applications-user_id_task_id_unique" 
ON public.task_applications 
USING btree (user_id, task_id)
```

Unfortunately in case of two concurrent transactions with same `user_id` and `task_id`, the second one always fail with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "task_applications-user_id_task_id_unique"
  Key (user_id, task_id)=(1, 1) already exists.
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it in order to be able to handle such situation in my service method?

**UPDATED**

I don't understand why the following method doesn't block the execution of second transaction until first transaction will be committed or rolled back:

```
TaskApplication taskApplication = taskApplicationRepository.findByUserAndTask(user, task);
```

I'm not sure about PostgreSQL, but typically it should block the execution based on unique index **in case of no record**.

How to achieve it?

**UPDATED 2**

The sequence of SQL commands generated during execution:

```
select * from task_applications taskapplic0_ where taskapplic0_.user_id=? and taskapplic0_.task_id=? for update of taskapplic0_
insert into task_applications values (?,...)
```

Comment: Use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: Thanks, but please see my updated question

Comment: I see the update, but don't understand the relevance of it.

Comment: The relevance of it is the following - I'm unable to handle the described issue on my service method. Synchronization lock mechanism doesn't work.

Comment: I use `Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` over `findByUserAndTask method`. In my understanding it should block execution of transaction #2 until transaction #1 will be committed or rolled back. And in order to archive it, it should use `task_applications-user_id_task_id_unique` index as a semaphore in case of attempt to create a new entity. But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the sequence of SQL commands generated during this transaction by spring-boot-data-jpa?  PostgreSQL doesn't lock the non-existence of rows except in serializable mode, and then the locks just serve to throw errors, not to block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with the sequence of SQL commands. What options I have now in order to lock the execution on code level and do not wait while PostgreSQL will throw duplicate key value error on insert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
TaskApplication findByUserAndTask(User user, Task task);
```

will obtain pessimitic lock only on entites returned by the query (row-level lock). In situation when result set is empty, no lock is being obtained and *findByUserAndTask* doesn't block transaction.

There are few ways how you could handle concurrent inserts:

1. Use unique index to prevent adding duplicates and handle exception proper to your application needs
2. If your database supports it, obtain table-level lock on the table where you want to insert data. JPA doesn't support it.
3. Emulate table-level lock using row-level lock on new entity & table dedicated for storing locks. This new table should have a row per each table on which you want to obtain pessimistic lock on insert

```
    public enum EntityType {
        TASK_APPLICATION
    }
```

```
    @Getter
    @Entity
    public class TableLock {
        @Id
        private Long id

        @Enumerated(String)
        private EntityType entityType;
    }
```

```
    public interface EntityTypeRepository extends Repository<TableLock, Long> {
        
        @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
        TableLock findByEntityType(EntityType entityType);
    }
```

Having such setup you just need to obtain lock:

```
@Transactional
public TaskApplication createIfNotExists(User user, Task task) {
    TaskApplication taskApplication = taskApplicationRepository.findByUserAndTask(user, task);

    if (taskApplication == null) {
        findByEntityType(EntityType.TASK_APPLICATION);
        taskApplication = taskApplicationRepository.findByUserAndTask(user, task);
        
        if (taskApplication == null) {
            taskApplication = create(user, task);
        }
    }

    return taskApplication;
}
```

For most cases first approach (unique index) is the best and most efficient. Obtaining table lock (native / emualated) is heavy and should be used with care.

> I'm not sure about PostgreSQL, but typically it should block the execution based on unique index in case of no record.

Presence of indices does not affect if select / insert statement are blocking or not. Such behaviour is controlled by pessimistic locks.